# Unable to get UIImage to fit custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hi guys I'm unable to make the image file the custom uitableview cell i made. The image is so small and i don't know how to enlarge it. Thnx in advance for the help.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customCell : UITableViewCell
{
  //UILabel *frontLabel;    
}
@property(nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property(nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property(nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

  customCell * cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }


  User * user = [self.list objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

  cell.label.text = user.username;
  NSString *url = user.profilePic;
  UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
  cell.imageView.contentMode =UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  cell.imageView.image =image;

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `customCell` class (btw all classes should start with a capital letter, properties and variables should be lowercase), you just need to set the `frame` property of your `imageView` object to the correct size and position you want.

Something like `imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10., 10., 50., 50.)` where the first two parameters are the x and y position of the top right corner of the image view, and the second two parameters are the width and height.

Or, since you have those properties specified as IBOutlet's, if you're using a XIB file for the layout, you should have the size setup already in there.

Without seeing a screenshot of Interface Builder for the XIB or the implementation code for `customCell`, that's the best I can help.

Comment: thnx, but i can't access the imageView form my custom class which is weird. I set property and synth it but when i tried to self.imageView it doesn't recognize it as key word

Comment: Well `UITableViewCell` already has an `imageView` property, so you should definitely be able to access it, but it looks like your `UIImageView` is `imgView`. You can just not use the built in `imageView` and use your `imgView` instead.

Comment: But also in your UITableViewController, when you're doing `cell.imageView` do `cell.imgView` to access the one you're adding to your custom cell.

Comment: no yea i got it, the closing brackets were off but for some reason the syntax didn't get highlighted in red !thnx for the help! For some reason i though you'd be able to do that when you set the cells. that was what i was trying the whole time.

Comment: Well in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should also be able to set the frame like `cell.imgView.frame = ` but if each of the custom cells are going to have the same image positioning, you should just do it right in your custom cell class.